# How to 8-byte align each string in a static array?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, clang

Imagine you have a static array of literal strings in a C program (not C++), the lengths of which can vary widely. All you care about is that each one starts on an 8-byte boundary. Is there a way to ensure that either GCC or CLANG will align each string thus?
You also want to conserve space, so padding the strings so they are all the same size is not an option.

```
static char* const strings[] = {
    "a", "longer string", "bcd", "wow a really long string", "foo", ...
};
```

The goal here is to do something like this:

```
uint64_t value = *(uint64_t*) strings[i];
```

such that the read does not straddle two quadwords in the generated asm code i.e. the first 8 bytes of the string go into a register using an aligned read.

Comment: You can use a union type that has an 8-byte alignment requirement. But first ask yourself this: why do you need this in the first place? It's most likely a bad idea.

Comment: I assure you it is a most excellent idea in my case.

Comment: This is an array of pointers, not an array of strings. Please clarify which one you meant. (And if you did mean an array of pointers, do you want the pointer addresses to be aligned, or the string literal addresses to be aligned?)

Comment: Using Clang I found that @aaaaaa123456789 's answer does not produce   assembly language with the strings aligned.

Comment: `uint64_t value = *(uint64_t*) strings[i];` is still undefined behaviour in C because it violates strict aliasing.  You want `memcpy(value, strings[i], sizeof(value));` which will inline away on platforms that support unaligned loads.  If you can communicate the alignment info to the compiler (e.g. by having an array of pointers to *aligned* strings or unions) then it should inline away even on MIPS64 or whatever platform that doesn't allow normal loads to be unaligned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you want the string literals to be aligned; this is not possible.  But you can get a similar effect by making arrays with custom alignment, e.g.:

```
_Alignas(8) static char const s1[] = {"a"};
_Alignas(8) static char const s2[] = {"longer string"};
_Alignas(8) static char const s3[] = {"bcd"};
_Alignas(8) static char const s4[] = {"wow a really long string"};
_Alignas(8) static char const s5[] = {"foo"};

char const *const strings[] = { s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 };
```

You could save typing by using a preprocessor macro for each entry.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529491/how-can-i-align-a-string-literal-to-an-address-which-is-multiple-of-4).

---

According to the C17 standard you can also use compound literals with alignment specifier:

```
char const *const strings[] = 
{
    (_Alignas(8) char const[]){"a"},
    (_Alignas(8) char const[]){"longer string"},
};
```

although some compilers don't support this yet.

Comment: To avoid creating all these external variables, one could also make the `sX` variables `static` or just use compound literals.

Comment: Using Clang on a Mac  I examined the assembly language (gcc -S) and your solution does work. It produces e.g.:    .p2align        3   
_s1:
        .asciz  "a"

Comment: @JensGustedt compound literals don't permit *alignment-specifier* according to the standard.  Agree with `static`

Comment: @M.M This had been an error in the specification that has been corrected in C17. It now says: *An alignment specifier shall appear only in the declaration specifiers of a declaration, or in the
specifier-qualifier list of a member declaration, or in the type name of a compound literal.*

Comment: @JensGustedt That is too bad. You know, many a-time I have wanted to make a suggestion on how to improve C, but there is no one who seems to be responsible or contactable anymore to take my input. (This would be such a case.) If this good feature has been removed, I may have to resort to storing these quadword-aligned string literals in an asm file.

Comment: @denk, I don't understand what is bad, here, this was an improvement in C17, no? And for the future of C it doesn't help to make suggestions, alone. Somebody got to do the work. So enroll in your contriies national standards body, and participate in WG14. We need all hands on deck.

Comment: @JensGustedt OK. I actually answered that way originally (see edit history) but found that the latest version of clang rejected the code with a syntax error, so I guess they haven't gotten around to applying C17 changes / DR .

Comment: I'd recommend `#include <stdalign.h>` so you can use `alignas()`, making this code valid C++ as well as valid C (and more importantly using a more familiar "keyword" for people who regularly deal with both languages.)

Comment: @PeterCordes maybe we could make some macros so the code is valid java, python and shell script also?

Comment: You don't prefer `alignas()` for C projects?  I know I do.  Maybe I could have picked a better justification.